# Razor broken when a space between HTML’s attribute and its value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `ViewBag` like this

```
ViewBag.ApplyDiscount = false;
ViewBag.ExpressShip = true;
ViewBag.Supplier = null;
```

and some `cshtml` snippets like this

```
Discount:<input type="checkbox" checked="@ViewBag.ApplyDiscount"/>
Express:<input type="checkbox" checked="@ViewBag.ExpressShip"/>
Supplier:<input type="checkbox" checked="@ViewBag.Supplier"/>
```

after razor rendered the `cshtml` snippets,the real html will be

```
Discount:<input type="checkbox"/>
Express:<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>
Supplier:<input type="checkbox"/>
```

but if I add a space between the `checked` attribute and `=`like

```
Discount:<input type="checkbox" checked ="@ViewBag.ApplyDiscount"/>
Express:<input type="checkbox" checked ="@ViewBag.ExpressShip"/>
Supplier:<input type="checkbox" checked ="@ViewBag.Supplier"/>
```

razor will render the `cshtml` snippet in a wrong way. The html will be like this:

```
Discount:<input type="checkbox" checked ="False"/>
Express:<input type="checkbox" checked ="True"/>
Supplier:<input type="checkbox" checked =""/>
```

This will happen no matter MVC4(VS2012) or MVC5(VS2015).

So, can anyone tell me why a space will cause this thing to happen?

Comment: Your use a `checked="@ViewBag.ExpressShip"` to generate `checked="checked"` is a feature of razor called conditional attributes introduced in MVC-4. Refer [this article](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/201/cleaner-conditional-html-attributes-in-razor-web-pages) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because checked itself is a special stand-alone boolean attribute from legacy HTML and can be valid syntax without an attribute value.

It's presence alone indicates that the box is checked.

e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

and

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="true" />
```

Perform the same way. It's why in jquery we always use the :checked selector. It obfuscates the need to check the variation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!!! This help me a lot to understanding this problem. So,this is not a razor bug.

Comment: My pleasure. Good luck with your app!